# Besides caching, how can I use more memory rather than cpu time on a LAMP server?

Tags: php, caching, memory-management, lamp

My site is rough on cpu usage, but I have plenty of memory (and hdd space) I could be using. The site is sort of a game with lots of db updates and object manipulations.  Generally speaking, is there any other way to share the load after having cached as much as I think I can?

Thanks

Comment: use a profiler to optimize the code? xdebug supports profiling...

Comment: Thanks!  I had no idea such programs existed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general advice I, am afraid.
Can't you at least roughly profile your application, to determine certain bottlenecks - if it's db updates, or object manipulations? Or even some other, obscure matter?

If your filesystem is a cheap one (not SAS), and there are many disk I/O, it may eat up your CPU easily. You have to optimize disk writes, but I am afraid again there is no common way. Try to reduce number of indexes. Cache your database in memory, when applicable.

Comment: Thats kinda what I was afraid of/expected.  After further review, I've gotten the db calls down to a minimum.  Its mainly just objects looping and incrementing counters in the guts of the program.  Not much disk I/O either.  I have no indexes, its mainly one table.  I've learned about query cache because of this.  I have query cache enabled and its somewhat applicable, but it shouldn't matter much.  I have identified a couple loops that could be better optimized, but it looks like there's not much I can do.  Thanks for reassuring me that I'm not forgetting something dumb :)

Comment: well, the only way left is to profile your math code. every code can be optimized - just profile it and find most CPU consuming parts and then optimize them. you may consider to code some parts in C, it will give you a huge boost no doubts.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, yet somehow I would have never thought of coding core modules in C.  Perhaps its because I found C to be too difficult :0  Thanks again

Comment: xdebug is just what I was looking for, I had no idea such a program existed